# Como automatizar download de PDF com selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando automatizar uma tarefa de entrar diariamente no Diário Oficial,

http://www.imprensaoficial.com.br

encontrar a data, a seção desejada e baixar cada página da seção em pdf. A numeração das páginas muda a cada dia porque cada seção tem dias que tem mais e dias que tem menos páginas.

Tentei inicialmente com urllib mas por ser um site .asp, não consegui fazer o scrapping.

Estou tentando pelo selenium mas ele não está identificando o campo 'Nome da Seção' onde eu precisaria selecionar o que desejo baixar.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get("http://www.imprensaoficial.com.br")
element = driver.find_element_by_id("okBuscaEdicao")
element.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("okBuscaEdicao")
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("pg")
```

Inspecionando o site, encontrei que o id do campo Nome da Seção é 'pg', mas o selenium não encontra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**EDIT**]

Sim usei a url que vc indicou e modifiquei "ligeiramente"

```py
import os

import lxml.html as parser
import requests


class DiarioOficial():
    _header = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36',
    }
    _url = 'http://diariooficial.imprensaoficial.com.br/nav_v5/header.asp?'

    def __init__(self, pasta_diario_oficial='diario_oficial'):
        self.pasta_diario_oficial = pasta_diario_oficial


    def get_cadernos(self, dia: str, mes: str, ano: str, caderno: str):
        """Funcao que recupera os cadernos e suas respectivas IDs

        Args:
            dia (str): dia ex: 18
            mes (str): mes ex: 06
            ano (str): ano ex: 2020
            caderno (str): nome do caderno ex: Empresarial 2
                rode sem parametros para listar os cadernos

        Returns:
            (str): ID do respectivo caderno
        """
        html_text = requests.get(
            f'{self._url}txtData={dia}/{mes}/{ano}&acao=1').content
        tree = parser.fromstring(html_text)
        count = 2
        print('Cadernos:\n')
        while True:
            try:
                list_element = tree.xpath(f'//*[@id="edicao"]/option[{count}]')
                caderno_nome = list_element[0].text.strip()
                caderno_numero = list_element[0].attrib.values()[0]
                print(f'{caderno_numero}: {caderno_nome}')
                if caderno_nome in caderno:
                    return caderno_numero
            except IndexError:
                break
            count += 1

    def _get_secoes(self, dia: str, mes: str, ano: str, edicao: str):
        """Funcao que recupera as secoes e o numero total de paginas

               Args:
                   dia (str): dia ex: 18
                   mes (str): mes ex: 06
                   ano (str): ano ex: 2020
                   edicao (str): id da edicao ex: '29257'

               Returns:
                   (list[list, str]): lista  com lista de secoes e string pag total
               """
        list_secoes = []
        html_text2 = requests.get(
            f'{self._url}txtData={dia}/{mes}/{ano}&edicao={edicao}&acao=1').content
        tree1 = parser.fromstring(html_text2)
        count = 2
        while True:
            try:
                list_element = tree1.xpath(f'//*[@id="pg"]/option[{count}]')
                numero = list_element[0].text
                list_secoes.append(numero.split(' .... '))
            except IndexError:
                break
            count += 1
        paginas = tree1.xpath('//*[@id="form"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span')
        pag_total = paginas[0].text.split('de ')[1].strip()
        return [list_secoes, pag_total]

    def save_page(self, pdf_url, dia: str, mes: str, ano: str, caderno: str, secao: str, page_count: str):
        pdf = requests.get(pdf_url).content
        with open(fr'{self.pasta_diario_oficial}/{ano}/{mes}/{dia}/{caderno}/{secao}/{secao}_{page_count}.pdf',
                  'wb') as f:
            f.write(pdf)

    @staticmethod
    def _cria_dir(caminho):
        if not os.path.exists(caminho):
            os.makedirs(caminho)

    def salvar_pdf(self, dia: str, mes: str, ano: str, caderno: str, secao: str):
        """Funcao principal que salva os PDFs.


        Args:
            dia (str): dia ex: 18
            mes (str): mes ex: 06
            ano (str): ano ex: 2020
            caderno (str): nome do caderno ex: "Empresarial 2".
             Para listar os cadernos rode com uma string vazia.

            secao (str): nome da secao ex: "PROCURADORIA GERAL DO MUNICÍPIO".
             Para listar as secoes rodecom uma string vazia.

        """
        print('[!]Rodando...\n')
        self._cria_dir(fr'{self.pasta_diario_oficial}/{ano}/{mes}/{dia}/{caderno}/{secao}')
        edicao = self.get_cadernos(dia, mes, ano, caderno)
        if edicao:
            list_secoes, pag_total = self._get_secoes(dia, mes, ano, edicao)
            if list_secoes:
                print(f'\nSecoes:\n{list_secoes}\n')
                for idx, val in enumerate(list_secoes):
                    # print(val[0])
                    idx += 1
                    inicial = int(val[1])
                    try:
                        final = int(list_secoes[idx][1]) + 1
                    except IndexError:
                        final = int(pag_total) + 1
                    nome_secao = val[0].replace('____', '')
                    if nome_secao in secao:
                        print('Salvando...')
                        for item in range(inicial, final):
                            # print(item)
                            html_text3 = requests.get(
                                f'{self._url}txtData={dia}/{mes}/{ano}&edicao={edicao}&pg={item}&acao=1').content
                            tree2 = parser.fromstring(html_text3)
                            paginas1 = tree2.xpath('/html/head/script[1]/text()')[0].split("'")[3]
                            print(paginas1)
                            self.save_page(paginas1, dia, mes, ano, caderno, nome_secao, str(item))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    diario = DiarioOficial()
    diario.salvar_pdf('26', '06', '2020', 'Cidade', 'GABINETE DO PRESIDENTE')
    # print('mmm', diario.get_cadernos('26', '06', '2020', ''))
```

Comment: Seu código funciona bem legal, mas o que vc tá chamando de seção é o caderno. a seção está dentro do caderno e ela não aparece no link. No caso, preciso delimitar uma seção dentro do Caderno Executivo, e essa seleção é feita pelo javascript, creio eu. ```http://diariooficial.imprensaoficial.com.br/doflash/prototipo/2020/Junho/27/exec1/pdf/pg_0055.pdf``` essa seção, nesse dia, começa na página 55.

Comment: O que você precisa é bastante complexo, deixa eu ver se eu entendi: Você quer um programa que faça uma busca ao entrar com parâmetros como data, caderno e o **nome da seção**  ex ('27', '06', '2020' '____Gabinete do Secretário' ) e que salve em uma pasta todos os PDF"s referente a seção, ou quer salvar **todas**  as "seções" de um dia especifico em arquivos separados?

Comment: na verdade, o caderno e a seção são sempre os mesmos, eu só mudaria o dia. Ele baixaria o pdf referente àquela seção. Eu consegui compreender o site e acho q não precisa de java. Nesse link ```http://diariooficial.imprensaoficial.com.br/nav_v5/header.asp?txtData=26/06/2020&cad=4&cedic=20200626&pg=1&acao=&edicao=&secao='``` ele muda a cada dia e dá pra encontrar a lista de seções e o respectivo número da página daquele dia. agora eu tô penando no seguinte: '____Gabinete do Secretário' é uma subseção que tem que vir junto com o primeiro nome sem o underscore.